# Huge delay for Kafka on Azure

Tags: azure, apache-kafka

I will start by saying i have very limited knowledge about both Kafka and Azure.
I'm just trying to see if i can contribute to solve this problem.

We have Kafka setup on Azure, and since a couple of month back we sometimes are not able to fetch messages. When its working, it always takes ~20.000 ms, no matter if we fetch 1 or 5000 messages.

When we launch Kafka tool from within Azure, it takes 600 ms, to fetch the messages.
So i believe its some 20.000 ms timeout that has been activated, but we cant figure out were.

We will now take a Wireshark capture from the client, but i thought it might be worth checking here as well, if someone else had similiar issues.

Comment: is it Kafka on Event Hubs? Kafka running on a VM?

Comment: It’s Kafka running on VM. 
We have looked at the connection and latency and has normal condition towards Azure. 
The strange thing is that it takes almost 20.000 ms every time when fetching the messages. Even if we fetch 1 or 5000 messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wireshark we could see the problem was with reverse DNS.